# How to use SUM and return all rows even where there is nothing to sum?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `USERS` and a table `ORDERS`. In my backend office I'm attempting to output a table with all users (customers) and `SUM` their individual order total, so to simplify I'm saying:

```
SELECT users.id, SUM(orders.total) as spent FROM users
    JOIN orders ON users.id=orders.customer_id GROUP BY users.id
```

(Note: *do not pay attention to the syntax, this is just to illustrate the point. the syntax is fine when I run it.*)

I now have say 4 **users** in total and the `ORDERS` table looks something like this:

```
order_id  customer_id  total
1         1            25
2         2            10
3         1            5
```

Then my query will output ONLY those **users** that can be found in the `ORDERS` table and my backend customer overview table will look unfortunately like this:

```
Customer ID      Spent in Total
1                30
2                10
```

ignoring completely the other 2 users who have not yet placed any orders. What I want to see is this:

```
Customer ID      Spent in Total
1                30
2                10
3                0
4                0
```

Is there a way to do this?

My guess is that it has something to do with special joins like inner, outer, but I don't know the difference there.

Also what I thought about was to run two queries, selecting `*` from users and then running a `foreach` to sum up order total, but this seems inefficient.

Comment: 'LEFT JOIN' is your friend

Comment: LEFT JOIN it was indeed. I was simply unaware of the different possible joins. Silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join, and on some (old) versions of MySQL also an `IFNULL()`.

```
SELECT 
  users.id, 
  IFNULL(SUM(orders.total),0) as spent 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON users.id=orders.customer_id 
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: IFNULL also seems to break the syntax on newer versions

Answer (score 4):

Because sometimes one picture is worth more than thousand words:

[image: SQL Joins]

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id, sum(o.Total)
from Users u
left outer join Orders o on u.id = o.customer_id
group by u.id
```